# Flutter setState() or markNeedsBuild() Error with async Navigations

Tags: flutter, navigator, flutterwebviewplugin

I am struggling with this error message: `(setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build`

I am trying to continue with a Navigator.pushNamed(..) after a first async Navigation had happened.

In my code below, I do return without crash for the first Navigator.pushNamed.

But then when I do another Navigator.pushNamed(..) right after it, the app crashes!

To make it more clear: The first navigation (i.e. to `payment_checkout_mobile`) opens a flutter_webview. Then some payment information can be given. The webview eventually closes by Navigator.of(context).pop(). Then I land inbetween the two Navigation-calls as can be seen in the code below.

But the big question: Why is the second Navigation crashing ????

```
onPressed: () async {
  String checkoutSessionUrl = await saveForm();
  if (!mounted) return;
  await Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/payment_checkout_mobile',
    arguments: PaymentCheckoutArguments(checkoutSessionUrl),
  );
  if (!mounted) return;
  // The code returns here without error !!!!!
  // But the next Navigation crashes - why ?????????????
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/payment_success_page');
},
```

The error message is:

```
FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This GetBuilder<ProductController> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this.

```
 Future.microtask(() => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/payment_success_page'));
```

Comment: None of the suggested ideas helped. Also `Future.microtask(...)` did not change anything, still the same crash!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

You can place the follwong:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/some_page_up_the_widget_hierarchy));
```

Just make sure that `/some_page_up_the_widget_hierarchy` corresponds to a page that you had already rendered in your widget-tree! (otherwise the pop will not go until the widget-hierarchy-location you intend)

Another solution that also works:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/some_page', (route) => true);
```

This will pop all widgets in the tree and render the new `/some_page`.

About the reason why the `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/payment_success_page')` did not work in the first place, I still have no clue. Maybe flutter has a limit of widgets you can push ??? Or maybe somebody knows why `popUntil` or `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` did work - but not `pushNamed` ??